# Save all HTML field names in Controller - it is bad or not bad idea?

Tags: php, laravel

I have sample controller `InboxController` in my Inbox app. I want control with field name from my controller. If I will control with fields name from controller will not be destroyed `MVC` rules?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class InboxController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Field names in HTML form
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * Recipient field name.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    public $recipient = 'recipient';

    /**
     * Sender field name.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    public $sender = 'sender';

    /**
     * Subject field name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
}
```

#### Html code:

```
<input type='text' name="{{ $sender }}">
```

Comment: what are we supposed to be reviewing here? the two controller properties? yes, those are very nice. i have no suggestions. if you want to do something with them and you're not sure how, you should try asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if it would be bad if the field names on the HTML form will be defined on the controller @I wrestled a bear once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you to use Symfony like form builder. There you can create one form and reuse it anywhere.

```
$form = FormFactory::create(FormType::class, $user)
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
        'rules' => 'unique:users,email',
    ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save user']);
```

What is also good is with this form you can also validate your input at the same time.

```
 $form->handleRequest();



 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      //Your code
 }
```

Here is [link for repository](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-form-bridge)